# How does one insert a key value pair into a python list?

Tags: python, list

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

i want to insert a:b into a blank python list

```
list = []
```

as

```
a:b
```

what is the proper syntax for this, to result in

```
[(a:b), (c:d)]
```

?

this is just so I can sort the list by value from least to greatest later

Comment: There is no "key-value pair" as a general thing in Python.  Why are you using a list instead of a dictionary?  A dictionary contains key-value pairs, but there's no builtin notion of a key-value pair that's not in a dictionary.

Comment: Please show us the expected output.

Comment: Do you want to query the list using the keys? If so, use a dictionary as @BrenBarn suggested. Otherwise, you can add a 2-tuple to your list if you just want to store "pairs of items": `my_list = [('a','b'),('c','d')]`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's assume your data looks like this:

```
a: 15
c: 10
b: 2
```

There are several ways to have your data sorted. This key/value data is best stored as a dictionary, like so:

```
data = {
    'a': 15,
    'c': 10,
    'b': 2,
}
# Sort by key:
print [v for (k, v) in sorted(data.iteritems())]
# Output: [15, 2, 10]
# Keys, sorted by value:
from operator import itemgetter
print [k for (k, v) in sorted(data.iteritems(), key = itemgetter(1))]
# Output: ['b', 'c', 'a']
```

If you store the data as a list of tuples:

```
data = [
    ('a', 15),
    ('c', 10),
    ('b', 2),
]
data.sort() # Sorts the list in-place
print data
# Output: [('a', 15), ('b', 2), ('c', 10)]
print [x[1] for x in data]
# Output [15, 2, 10]
# Sort by value:
from operator import itemgetter
data = sorted(data, key = itemgetter(1))
print data
# Output [('b', 2), ('c', 10), ('a', 15)]
print [x[1] for x in data]
# Output [2, 10, 15]
```

Answer (score 22):

***How does one insert a key value pair into a python list?***

You can't. What you can do is "imitate" this by appending tuples of 2 elements to the list:

```
a = 1
b = 2
some_list = []
some_list.append((a, b))
some_list.append((3, 4))
print some_list
>>> [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

But the correct/best way would be using a dictionary:

```
some_dict = {}
some_dict[a] = b
some_dict[3] = 4
print some_dict
>>> {1: 2, 3: 4}
```

**Note:**

- Before using a dictionary you should read the Python documentation, some tutorial or some book, so you get the full concept.
- Don't call your list as `list`, because it will hide its built-in implementation. Name it something else, like `some_list`, `L`, ...

Comment: I believe this actually answers the question. Though I don't know if the OP knew about dictionaries or if he has a constraint not to use it.

Comment: The `some_d[a]=b` way seems best to insert key-value pairs into a dict with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Overview: In this code sample I demonstrate how to tokenize a list of sentences and then store a dictionary containing a key and value pair where the value is the tokenized words with occurrence count for each sentence.

```
index=np.arange(0,len(sentences))  
wordfreq = {}
bagList=[]
for i in index:
    sentence=sentences[i]
    keyId=keys[i]
    if(len(sentence)>0):
       tokens=sum([word_tokenize(sentence)],[])
       words_frequency = FreqDist(tokens)
       wordfreq={}
       for token in tokens:
           if token not in wordfreq.keys():
               wordfreq[token] = 1
           else:
               wordfreq[token] += 1
        
       bagList.append({'keyId':keyId, 'words': wordfreq})
```

to enumerate the list of dictionary items use

```
 for dictionaryValues in bagList:
     print(dictionaryValues['keyId'])
     print(dictionaryValues['words'])
```

to get back the key value pair use items

```
uncommon=dict()

for dictionaryItem in bagList:
    words=dictionaryItem['words']
    for key,(word,count) in enumerate(words.items()):
        if word in uncommon:
            uncommon[word]+=1
        else:
            uncommon[word]=1

 uncommon = {key: value for key, value in uncommon.items() if (value<=3 )}
```