# Why converting dictionaries to lists only returns keys?

Tags: python

I am wondering why when I use list(dictionary) it only returns keys and not their definitions into a list?

For example, I import a glossary with terms and definitions into a dictionary using CSV reader, then use the built in list() function to convert the dictionary to a list, and it only returns keys in the list.

It's not really an issue as it actually allows my program to work well, was just wondering is that just how it is supposed to behave or?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Because a dictionary is an iterable over its keys. You can use `list(mydict.items())` to retrieve a list of 2-tuples in the list.

Comment: The fact that it iterates over the keys makes it in harmony with the `in` behavior: it means that if you write `x in mydict`, then `x in list(mydict)` will suceed as well, and vice versa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one insert a key value pair into a python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496596/how-does-one-insert-a-key-value-pair-into-a-python-list)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I don't really understand because I am only a beginner programmer. As long as it works it's ok, I will figure out the theory some other time :)

Comment: Well, what *should* be the behavior of iterating (“looping”) over a dict or of turning it into a list? There’s no obvious “right” answer here. It’s defined as iterating over the keys.

Comment: [because that's how it's designed to work](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). "Performing list(d) on a dictionary returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary"

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean by:

```
>>> d = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
>>> d.items()
dict_items([('a', [1, 2, 3]), ('b', [4, 5, 6])])
>>> list(d.items())
[('a', [1, 2, 3]), ('b', [4, 5, 6])]
>>>
```

Dictionary makes `list(d)` give it's keys, however `list(d.values())` will give the values.

Also, in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> Performing list(d) on a dictionary returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary.

That tells you all.

Comment: I don't think so?

Comment: @Hydra17 "I don't think so" try it first!

Comment: No I mean, it probably works but I was just looking for a theoretical understanding of why the code I am using behaves the way it does. I think the others have explained it but tbh I don't have a baldies what they are on about because I'm a newbie lol Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: @DavidZemens Ah you got that documentation just before me, can i add that to my post.

Answer (score 1):

> why when I use list(dictionary) it only returns keys? ... just wondering is that just how it is supposed to behave or?

[Because that's how it's designed to work](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

> Performing list(d) on a dictionary returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary.

Because (speculative):

> The main operations on a dictionary are storing a value with some key and extracting the value given the key.

The *values* are not so consequential. Keys are unique identifiers. Values are mapped to keys. So dicts are indexed by key, iterated by key, etc. If you want a list of key/value tuple, then you have to call for that explicitly e.g., `list(d.items())`.

Answer (score 0):

Dictioanries are iterable over their key values hence you get only the key values returned when you wrap it with the `list()` function.

The behaviour would be something like this:

```
>>> dictionary = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
>>> dictionary.items()
dictionary_items([('item_1', [1, 2]), ('item_2', [3, 4])])
```

You can make use of `dictionary.items()` to get all the items(keys and values) from the dictionary

```
>>> list(dictionary.items())
[('item_1', [1, 2]), ('item_2', [3, 4])]
```

Answer (score 0):

**In short**: In essence it works that way, because it was *designed* that way. It makes however sense if we take into account that `x in some_dict` performs a membercheck on the dictionary keys.

---

Frequently Python code iterates over a collection, and does not know the type of the collection it iterates over: it can be a list, tuple, set, dictionary, range object, etc.

The question is, *do* we see a dictionary as a collection, and if yes, a collection of *what*? If we want to make it collection, there are basically three logical answers to the second question: we can see it as a collection of the keys, of the values, or key-value pairs. Especially keys and key-value pairs are popular. C# for example sees a dictionary as a collection of `KeyValuePair<TK, TV>`s. Python provides the `.values()` and `.items()` method to iterate over the values and key-value pairs.

Dictionaries are mainly designed to perform a fast lookup for a key and retrieve the corresponding value. Therefore the `some_key in some_dict` would be a sensical query, or `(some_key, some_value) in some_dict`, since the latter chould check if the key is in the dictionary, and then check if it matches with `some_value`. The latter is however less flexible, since often we might not want to be interested in the corresponding value, we simply want to check if the dictionary contains a certain key. We furthermore can not support both use cases concurrently, since if the dictionary would for example contain 2-tuples as keys, then that means it is ambiguous if `(1, 2) in some_dict` would mean that for key `1` the value is `2`; or if `(1, 2)` is a key in the dictionary.

Since the designers of Python decided to define the membership check on dictionaries on the keys, it makes more sense to make a dictionary an iterable over its keys. Indeed, one usually expects that if `x in some_iterable` holds, then `x in list(some_iterable)` should hold as well. If the iterable of a dictionary would return 2-tuples of key-value pairs (like C# does), then if we would make a list of these 2-tuples, it would not be in harmony with the membership check on the dictionary itself. Since if `2 in some_dict` holds, `2 in list(some_dict)` would fail.